# In Netsuite, how can I automatically send an email to a specific customer when their case is closed?

Tags: email, notifications, netsuite

I have one specific customer in NetSuite who is not receiving the automatic email notifications about their case when it is closed. All other customers are currently receiving and this customer received the emails up until about a year ago. Is this maybe an issue with the customer unsubscribing to the email updates? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: They may have unsubscribed.  Double-check their customer account, as well, to ensure that their email is correct.  Check to see if the cases show that they actually sent an email.

Comment: Also, check Lists > Relationships > Bounced Email Addresses and see if their email address is listed there.

Comment: I checked that the email is correct. There are no logs showing that the email bounced. But when I look at the case communications, no email is shown as being sent/attempted to be sent, unlike the other cases.